# Creative menu designs in wpf4

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-4.0

Currently our menus are laid out in a very boring fashion in plain vertical manner and my boss is continously pushing me to make the design attractive and creative. I am not that creative at designing menus. Whatever little animation I knew I have applied.

What more can be done? Can anybody give me some sample in WPF4 which lays out items in nice creative manner so I can take some inspiration?

Comment: This question might get a better response from http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Fortunately (or unfortunately) requests for examples/samples are off-topic: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of things:

- You can make it into a scrolling carousel (scrolls and wraps around)
- You can make it so it hide into the side (collapsable)
- You can copy what apple does and enlarge the area that you are hovering around (bubble effect).
- You can make selections flash twice before executing
- Animations (yes I know you said you included this) are a definite plus (make sure they don't eat away your resources and make it laggy though).
- If you use submenus, don't use the same old same old slide out or the such, make them rotate out (if you ever saw the movie Percy Jackson & The Olympians: Lightning Thief - The shield he gets starts off as a sliver, then spins open, quite nice).

Mainly, think about what you can do with the Adorner class, Animations, Rotation/Transform, Effects (WPF FX), etc. The "miscellaneous" stuff.